# Java Quartz job inside a Container

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Scheduled the first java Quartz job successfully with the instructions mentioned in - http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/examples/Example1

Since its a standalone application, we are using main method. I want to make it a container managed one. So, i added the code as per the instructions in - http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/ServletInitScheduler

But am unable to run the job automatically at the scheduled time, with in the container environment. I have to still use the main method and run the job manually.

Please suggest me a solution for this.

Here is the link for the quartz scheduler code.
https://gist.github.com/60b236e7fd1432c76248

Comment: Is the servlet starting up OK? Where are your jobs being stored? In memory or in a database?

Comment: Yes, the servlet is starting up and when tomcat server starts, and its entering into the execute method of the class that implements job interface. Jobs are stored in database, inside table  QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS

Comment: I am getting this message in the Apache Tomcat Logs -               Jun 28, 2012 3:52:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: QuartzInitializer: Storing the Quartz Scheduler Factory in the servlet context at key: org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.KEY

Comment: "and its entering into the execute method of the class that implements job interface" -> So the web container is running your jobs? You might need to show some code in the question i.e. show how you're actually able to kick jobs off inside this "main" method.

Comment: added link for code in the question.

Comment: I can see the code, thanks for that. So are you submitting a job and storing it in the JDBC tables? Then you startup Tomcat and the servlet should start Quartz, it should pickup that job and execute it. Exactly how are you submitting the job? Within another servlet or externally somehow?

Comment: so far i was using the CronTriggerExample.java as in the code link, to  trigger the job. But that was a standalone approach. But in order to set it inthe tomcat container how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a couple of issues to sort out.

1. Check the quartz docs and mod your web.xml to use either the listener or servlet approach. You currently have both.
2. You need another servlet to run inside tomcat to create a job. Google for how to create a simple servlet or ask for more info. You must grab the scheduler factory created by the quartz init servlet - check the javadocs for the quartz init servlet for how to do this. They make it available on the servlet context for other servlets to grab

Comment: Yep! added a java class that implements ServletContextListener and initializes the Quartz Scheduler @ startup, Storing jobs in Jobstore.. Added that in web.xml. Thanks for all your support..:)